# How to change the pagination number format of datatables to another locale?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

How do I change the pagination number format of databales to another locale format, i.e. Arabic number format. I have read the datatables manual(https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/language.html) and MDN(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) but failed to find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices (as far as I can tell) :

1. Alter the code, specifically the internal function `pageButton` added to `DataTable.ext.renderer` about line 14205 (v 1.10.7)

   ```
   $.extend( true, DataTable.ext.renderer, {
       pageButton: {
   ```

   change the code about line 14258 from

   ```
   default:
       btnDisplay = button + 1;
       btnClass = page === button ?
       classes.sPageButtonActive : '';
       break;
   ```

   to

   ```
   default:
       btnDisplay = new Intl.NumberFormat('ar-EG').format(button + 1);
       btnClass = page === button ?
       classes.sPageButtonActive : '';
       break;
   ```
2. Replace the rendered content upon the `draw.dt` event

   ```
   $('#example').on('draw.dt', function() {
      $('.paginate_button').not('.previous, .next').each(function(i, a) {
         var val = $(a).text();
         val = new Intl.NumberFormat('ar-EG').format(val);
         $(a).text(val);
      })
   });
   ```

   Guess the pagination should look something like this

   [image]

   demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hojpyahy/**

Answer (score 0):

They have internationalisation plug-ins for changing locale format.

See this example using ajax , they changed language to german in this example :
https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/][1](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/)

Similarly, you can do for arabic.

Comment: It helps a lot translating the strings but fails to show the numbers in the locale format.