# Change pagination number to arabic in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm unable to change the **previous** and **next** text in Arabic using

```
"paginate" : { 
      "next" : " "
  }
```

How can I change the number format of pages to **Arabic** format?

Comment: Did you find any answer?

Comment: No Rakesh.. no answer

Answer (score 1):

To change the text into a language you want just put this code in the datatable init:

```
    table.DataTable({
        "language": {
            "paginate": {
              "first": "الصفحة الأولى",
              "last": "الصفحة الأخيرة",
              "next": "التالي",
              "previous": "السابق",
            }
        }
    });
```

and that's how you change the language of these texts:
[changed text example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNoZW.png)

and if you want to change the number format you can find the answer in the following link:
[change pagination number format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556381/how-to-change-the-pagination-number-format-of-datatables-to-another-locale)